# How to add a list of custom bad/forbidden words to Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a list of words/phrases that I would like Visual Studio Code to underline when they occur in the project. The list is custom. How to accomplish it?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight

Comment: @riov8 please add it as an answer so i can vote on it. Ita great extension. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the extension Highlight mentioned by @rioV8, but what it misses is:

1) You can not provide a message when code part triggers RegEx

2) It highlights with different colors (it's nice). But it does not use Lenses in Visual Studio Code.

So i wrote an extension that does that. Shows message when code triggers RegEx in realtime. You can think of it like as an Uber Linter.

[image]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomasz-smykowski.assistant

You can find it above and install. Also there is source code available on GitHub

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) to give particular text a different color.